# Webtorrent in Meteor fails when loaded via NPM. Not via CDN

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm, webtorrent

When I import the `webtorrent` package via `import  WebTorrent  from 'webtorrent'` and try to set up the package with `var client = new WebTorrent()` I get

```
tcp-pool.js:22 Uncaught TypeError: net.createServer is not a function
```

But when I use `$.ajax()` to load the `CDN` hosted version it works.

This is both `clientside`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been with meteor.

https://github.com/feross/webtorrent/issues/804
Here is the description.